# Pre and Post intervention with no pairing

Tags: t-test

My sample size is small (n= 28). I have 2 cohorts who have carried out the same interventions at different times. I have collected pre and post intervention scales for both groups. What I have not done is pair the data, as it was anonymous. This is part of a bigger qualitative study. Any suggestions which test I should use to see if there are any differences in the scale scores pre and post?

Comment: The point here is that the data actually are paired, you just don't know the pairing, is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, it is from the same group pre and post